# Sharing Session with ApplicationInsights TelemetryInitializer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have tried to share Session with azure telemetry.

I have installed nuget package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.
I have tried to get session key-value from my app session in my MyInitializer class which derived from ITelemetryInitializer.

MyInitializer Initialize method

```
var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
if (ctx != null)
{
    var tel = ctx.GetRequestTelemetry();       
    var companyId = tel.Context.Properties["MyKeyInAppSession"];
}
```

In my App_Start.NinjectWebCommon

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new 
MyInitializer());
```

Unfortunately it always throw KeyNotFoundException (I have try catch block there, but here not included to simplify). Is there something I am missing?

Comment: *it always throw exception* -> care to share what exception?

Comment: edited: KeyNotFoundException

Comment: on what line, what is the stacktrace? Did you debug to see MyKeyInAppSession is actual present?

Comment: of course in the line where dictionary is: var companyId = tel.Context.Properties["MyKeyInAppSession"]; It is not present. If it would be present, I would have not ask.